# Saving document using NSFileWrapper

Tags: macos, cocoa, save-as, nsfilewrapper

I'm developing an document-based application that allow users to insert images, movies to make compositions.

When saving the document, I create a directoryFileWrapper in which I put the xml representation of my project, and one fileWrapper for each images/movies using the original path (if document is not saved yet) or the it's relative path inside the package.

Once it's saved, users can move the document to another location/mac and still have access to their content.

If user do a "SaveAsOperation", and save it at the same location, the document is first deleted, and then I have to recreate it. The problem is that I can't recreate the fileWrappers using the relative path, as the document itself is already deleted.

Is there a way to prevent it to happen?
What's the right way to save existing files into packages?

Comment: Which method of NSDocument did you override?

Comment: -fileWrapperOfType: error:

Comment: -readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error:

Comment: Those are for reading. Which method of NSDocument did you override for writing? Did you try `-[NSDocument writeToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error:]`?

Comment: -fileWrapperOfType: error: is called during the write operation. I tried writeToURL, but the file is deleted before this call.

Comment: fileWrapperOfType is for writing, I'm sorry. How do you do SaveAsOperation? Save As… isn't in the File Menu anymore.

Comment: Save As... still exist, go in file menu with alt key down and "duplicate" menu item change to Save As...

Comment: Aha. But `-[NSDocument writeToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error:]` works.

Comment: writeToURL:ofType:error: also works, the file isn't deleted yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is:

in .h

- create an instance var NSFileWrapper.

In the init:

- create an empty directoryFileWrapper.

Each time you want to add a file in the wrapper:

- add this file inside the directoryFileWrapper

In -readFromFileWrapper:(NSFileWrapper *)inFileWrapper ofType:error:

- make "inFileWrapper" your fileWrapper (don't forget to release previous and retain the new one)

In -fileWrapperOfType:error:

- return you fileWrapper.

If you also want to use NSFileWrapper, this link may be helpful
https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/09/back-on-mac-os-x-tutorial-for-ios-developers/
and the github repo is https://github.com/Cocoanetics/Examples